# Зацикливается на пустом месте в конце функции

Tags: c++, функции

Когда я сохраняю данные вводя цифру 5 оно выполняет все инструкции в теле функции и зацикливается на пустом месте.
функция сохранение:

```
void save_settings()
    {
        ofstream file("Settings.json");
        if (file.is_open())
        {
            cout << "Saving..." << endl;
            file << hack_level << " " << pc_level << " " << proxy_level << " " << language;
            //file << language << " ";
            cout << "Saved!" << endl;//Сохряняем настройки
            file.close();
        }
    }
```

Функция лобби

```
void lobby()
    {
        //load_settings();
        if (language == "ru")
        {
            int what_to_do;
            cout << "\nВы в лобби!\nДействие:\nИзменение языка: - 1\nУзнать все уровни: - 2\nУлучшить что-то - 3\nВзломать что-то - 4\nСохранить данные - 5\nВыйти из игры - 6" << endl;
            cin >> what_to_do;
            if (what_to_do == 1)
            {
                lang();
            }
            else if (what_to_do == 2)
            {
                tell_all();
            }
            else if (what_to_do == 3)
            {
                update_lvl();
            }
            else if (what_to_do == 4)
            {
                what_to_hack();
            }
            else if (what_to_do == 5)
            {
                save_settings();
            }
            else if (what_to_do == 6)
            {
                exit(0);
            }
        }
        else if (language == "en")
        {
            int what_to_do;
            cout << "\nYou are in lobby!\nYou can:\nChange language: - 1\nKnow all levels: - 2\nUpdate something - 3\nHack something - 4\nSave data: - 5\nExit from this game - 6" << endl;
            cin >> what_to_do;
            if (what_to_do == 1)
            {
                lang();
            }
            else if (what_to_do == 2)
            {
                tell_all();
            }
            else if (what_to_do == 3)
            {
                update_lvl();
            }
            else if (what_to_do == 4)
            {
                what_to_hack();
            }
            else if (what_to_do == 5)
            {
                save_settings();
            }
            else if (what_to_do == 6)
            {
                exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
```

Функция запуска игры:

```
void starting_game()
    {
        load_settings();
        tell_hi();
        while (true)
        {
            lobby();
        }
    }
```

Если что то еще надо пишите!

Comment: Так у тебя у самого нет условия прерывания цикла.. У тебя написано `while(true)`. Чтобы выйти из цикла, нужно как минимум сделать break. В какой момент это делать - это уже тебе решать. Но суть в этом

Comment: Ты не понял после запуска функции сохранение оно выполняет все инструкции а дальше нечего не пишет хотя емли выбрать любой другой пункт то после выполнение например изменение языка он выводят вы находитеся в лобби!

Comment: Также если запустить просто функцию сохранение то оно выполняет все действие и оканчивает приложение

Comment: а для выхода из лобби можно выбрать пункт 6

Comment: Проще всего запустить в отладчике, установить точку останова на `save_settings` и посмотреть что именно происходит